# Can I get to a specific value inside of an object in an array by using another value in that object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have multiple arrays with objects inside that have three key/value pairs a name, a phone number and initials. I have a loop that creates a list of checkboxes and sets the initials value as it's class. I'm trying to figure out how to pull the phone number value from the corresponding object when the box is checked and save it into a separate array. Ex: If the box with the class '.BRJ' is checked save the 1222222222 number from that object into a new array.

I know I can run a function onclick in the input but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get to the phone number that matches that checkbox.

```
const management = [
  { name: 'Bob Jones', number: 12222222222, initials: 'BRJ',},
  { name: 'Peter Jones', number: 1333333333, initials: 'PRJ',},   
];

const operatorLoop = (shift, list) => {

  for (var i = 0; i < shift.length; i++) {
    list.innerHTML += `
    <li><input type = 'checkbox' class ='${shift[i].initials}' 
    >${shift[i].name}</input></li>
  `}
}

operatorLoop(management, mgmtUl);
```

Comment: 1) Get the class name of the clicked checkbox from inside the onclick event handler. 2) Look up the corresponding object using `Array.prototype.find()`. 3) Get the object's `number` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually set the phone number in the data attribute of the `<li>` element and, on clicking of the checkbox, get the data attribute value and push it to the phone numbers array.

```
const selectedPhoneNumbers = [];
function clickHandler(e) {
  const phoneNumber = e.target.getAttribute('data-phone');
  selectedPhoneNumbers.push(phoneNumber);
}
const operatorLoop = (shift, list) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < shift.length; i++) {
    list.innerHTML += `
      <li><input type = 'checkbox' data-phone='${shift[i].number}' class ='${shift[i].initials}'>
        ${shift[i].name}</input>
      </li>`
   }
}
```

This way, you won't have to `find` the clicked item from the object(which is internally another loop inside the array).

Comment: I'm pretty new at this and teaching myself. Thought I was a little in over my head but this worked and was super easy for me to understand. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

The first, you should add more attribute have the value is phone

```
const operatorLoop = (shift, list) => {
   for (var i = 0; i < shift.length; i++) {
      list.innerHTML += `
       <li><input type = 'checkbox' data-number='${shift[i].number}' class ='${shift[i].initials}' 
       >${shift[i].name}</input></li>`
   }
}
```

Then you get all checkboxs checked

```
var sList = "";
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    sList += (this.checked ? "," + $(this).data('number') : "");
});
console.log (sList); //result that you expect: 12222222222, 1333333333
```